# Trying to run the Main file of the wallet template from bitcoinj but JavaFX not found

Tags: bitcoinj

Trying to run the Main file of the wallet template from bitcoinj but JavaFX not found. When I run the main file of the wallettemplate I get multiple errors of javafx packages not found. When I try to run the entire thing I get an error missing a cucumber thing.

All the tutorials are outdated and I have only coded basic stuff.

Has anyone tried to use bitcoinj on intellij and java 10? Thank you.

Comment: yes, kindly post the logs

Answer (score 2):

The JavaFX was removed from JDK > 8 of java.

Now reside is an open-source module of java, look at the [official documentation](https://openjfx.io/).

Are available more plugins (maven and Gradle) for including the JavaFX in your project, [look here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs)

Answer (score 0):

Install the JavaFX SDK

Check this

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation/jfxpub-installation.htm

Comment: This answer is wrong, you have posted the the oracle documentation but the JavaFX jdk is no longer contained within. Now the JavaFX reside here for version > 9 of java